# How to delete old versions of Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have to free some space in my hard disk, and looking for what to delete I found that I have many Android Studio (AS) folders refering to old versions.

The route where I found that folders is: `C:\Users\mysuername`

[image]

What I want is the way to delete the older versions and just have the lastest one (in that moment ASPreview 1.3).

I have just to delete the folders and will be ok? Or I have to do something more to don't "break" AS?

Answer (score 2):

You can also delete the older version folders instead of completely removing the `Android studio` as you mentioned go to `C:\Users\yourUsername` and delete older version folder.

Comment: So it's ok to just delete the folders? It won't mess else anything up with the registry or whatnot?

Comment: when a new version get installed all the necessary settings and necessary folders are now in new version. If you delete the old version folder Android studio will work fine