# How to completely remove old version of Android studio from windows 10

Tags: android, flutter

I am trying to setup Flutter in my windows system. When I run the `flutter doctor`, I get this error.

[image]

I can clearly see there are multiple versions of Android Studio  So I tried these posts to remove the Android studio from my machine.
[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39953495/how-to-completely-uninstall-android-studio-from-windowsv10)
[Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30666395/how-to-delete-old-versions-of-android-studio)

It still shows the same error. How do I remove Android Studio completely from my machine?

Comment: Have you installed Flutter and Dart plugin for Android Studio?

Comment: Yes, you can see in the screenshot that it is installed for only one version of android studio, for the other, it is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up resetting up my OS, apparently, my windows username had space in it, so it was throwing an error. Once I reset my system, I just followed the steps from flutter documentation. Everything worked smoothly after that.

Answer (score 2):

It happened to me also, but I am using Mac OSX.
The solution is simple, you have to add to the Flutter config a pointing path to the new Android Studio installations. Check where it are, put the correct path. Like this:

```
flutter config --android-studio-dir "/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents"
```

If you are using Windows system:

```
flutter config --android-studio-dir "C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to install dart and flutter plugins,
As flutter documentation https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/editor.

Install the Flutter and Dart plugins
To install these:

Start Android Studio.
Open plugin preferences (Preferences > Plugins on macOS, File > Settings > Plugins on Windows & Linux).
Select Browse repositories, select the Flutter plugin and click Install.
Click Yes when prompted to install the Dart plugin.
Click Restart when prompted.

Comment: I have already installed Flutter and dart plugin in Android studio, as you can see in the screenshot that it is not complaining for Android Studio(3.4 version), but it is complaining about the old version of Android Studio. The question is how to remove that old version of Android Studio.